# MySQL sql_mode for remote access

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have setup MySQL with the default conf /etc/my.cnf as following:

```
[mysqld]

user=root

innodb_file_per_table

innodb_file_format=Barracuda

innodb_large_prefix

log_bin_trust_function_creators

sql-mode='NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER'

max_sp_recursion_depth=10

show_compatibility_56=ON

performance_schema

character-set-server=utf8mb4

[client]

socket=/home/abc/mysql_home/socket

[mysql]

default-character-set=utf8mb4
```

Accordingly, when I run `select @@global.sql_mode, @@session.sql_mode, @@sql_mode;` from Linux machine, I see :

```
NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER | NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER | NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER 

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Where as if I connect to the same instance and same user from the Windows machine (SQL developer), I see the following :

```
 NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER |STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER |STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER 

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Basically, mode `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` is getting added for the session variable though I have not made any session level updates. This MySQL strict mode is causing further issues.

Would like to know how this `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` is getting added by default only for the remote connection?

Commands used for creating the user :

```
CREATE USER 'USER_MYSQL'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'USER_MYSQL';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USER_MYSQL'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
CREATE USER 'USER_MYSQL'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'USER_MYSQL';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USER_MYSQL'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USER_MYSQL'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Using MySQL 5.7 version.

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/my.cnf` is not the only place to get such things.  It sounds as if you have a `.my.cnf` / `my.ini` file in your 'home' directory on Windows.

Which version of 5.7 are you using?  (There were several changes to `sql_mode`.)

What client are you using?  Perhaps it is injecting changes to `sql_mode` to mess with your head.